# Forma correta de enviar uma requisição

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, mongodb, express.js

Estou construindo uma API de teste para aprendizagem, e com algumas pesquisas observei que tinha uma falha na segurança.

O problema consistia durante o processo de autenticação, caso a requisição fosse passada com `{"$gte":""}` no campo e-mail, era retornado um usuário autenticado junto com o token, observei que possui uma biblioteca atualmente para ajudar nessa verificação ([express-mongo-sanitize](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mongo-sanitize)), ela funcionou super bem, mas com isso surgiu uma dúvida.

O meu model User está mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique: true
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        select: false
    },
    contact: {
        city: {
            type: String,
        },
        telephone: {
            type: String,
        }
    },
```

Eu não quero enviar todo o objeto para ser atualizado, preciso enviar apenas os campos que desejo, então utilizei o método PATCH.

Me deparei na seguinte situação:

Eu estava enviando o para a requisição um objeto mais ou menos dessa forma:

```
{
    "name": "Lucas",
    "contact.city": "Alterosa"
}
```

Mas pelo que observei os caracteres "$" e "." são reservados do MongoDB, então como eu teria que enviar essa informação caso desejasse apenas realizar a o update de name e city?

Da forma que é enviado acima é necessário apenas utilizar o seguinte código para update:

```
const user = await User.updateOne(
   { '_id': req.userId },
   {
      '$set': req.body
   }
)
```

Uma outra forma que fiz isso seria a seguinte:

```
 let setUpdate = {} // variavel para setar no update
        Object.entries(req.body).forEach(([k, v]) => { // Passo por todos os objetos pegando o campo (k) e valor (v)
            let notUpdate = [ '_id']
            let fieldsContact = ['city', 'telephone']

            if( notUpdate.includes(k) ){

            } else if ( fieldsContact.includes(k) ){ // verifico se algum conteúdo existe de contato
                setUpdate[`contacts.${k}`] = v
            } else {
                setUpdate[k] = v
            }
        })

        let user = await User.updateOne(
            { '_id': id },
            {
                "$set": setUpdate,
            }
        )
```

Mas é necessário realizar um caminho um pouco maior para conseguir o resultado desejado.

1- Gostaria de saber a forma correta de enviar os objetos nas requisições, se pode ser enviado com o caractere "." ou não?

2- A forma que utilizei para chegar ao resultado agrava em alguma coisa?

3- O que um usuário mal intencionado conseguiria fazer se enviasse na requisição o "."?